# Как импортировать npm пакет не прописывая путь к файлу напрямую

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

Ситуация следующая: создаю свой npm пакет, другие npm пакеты можно подключать используя имя папки, не прописывая путь до .js файла, мой нельзя. Объясните, пожалуйста, как это исправить.

При попытке подключить его, как другие попытки, выдает ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка на мой npm пакет: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs5-input-count
Ссылка на npm пакет для примера: https://swiperjs.com/get-started
Подключение другого пакета:

```js
import swiper from 'swiper'
```

Подключение моего пакета:

```js
import Bs5InputCount from '../../node_modules/bs5-input-count/scripts/theme.js';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Поле `exports`

Вы должны указать поле `exports` и путь к файлу в нём в `package.json`

**package.json**

```json
{
  "exports": "./scripts/theme.js"
}
```

Тогда вы сможете:

```js
import Bs5InputCount from 'bs5-input-count'
```

или

```json
{
  "exports": {
    ".": "./scripts/theme.js"
  }
}
```

#### Подробнее читайте [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/company/space307/blog/546240/)

Comment: Да, помогло, спасибо большое